# Creating lambda function by reading content of XML file

Tags: python, xml, lambda

I need to dynamically create lambda functions based on XML content in Python, in order to filter out some data.

Here is an example of how the conditions of the lambda function are arranged in XML format:

```
<conditions>
    <or>
        <and>
              <eq>
                 <field>is_hazardous</field>
                 <literal>1</literal>
              </eq>
              <eq>
                 <field>is_refrigeration</field>
                 <literal>0</literal>
              </eq>
              <not-eq>
                 <field>year</field>
                 <literal>2005</literal>
              </not-eq>>
              <not-eq>
                 <field>material</field>
                 <literal>plastic</literal>
              </not-eq>>
        </and>
        <eq>
             <field>is_active</field>
             <literal>1</literal>
        </eq>>
    </or>
</conditions>
```

- The **conditions** tag will always be the same.
- The tags **field** and **literal** will always children of **eq** and / or **not-eq**.

And here is a set of data in CSV format:

```
is_hazardous,is_refrigeration,year,material,is_active
1,0,2006,metal,1
1,0,2005,metal,0
```

What I need to achieve is:

```
def eval_data(x):
    return (
                   (
                       (x['is_hazardous'] == 1) and
                       (x['is_refrigeration'] == 0) and
                       (x['year'] != 2005) and (x['material'] != 'plastic'))
                or (x['is_active'] == 1)
           )

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df['check'] = df.apply(lambda x: eval_data(x),
                       axis = 1)
```

This function should output *True* for the first row and *False* for the 2nd one.

How can I dynamically create the return expression of the **eval_data** function from reading the content of the XML file?

Comment: Do you want to dynamically create a file.py with such function, or just have a function which checks such xml conditions dinamically?

Comment: I need the latter: a function, or a set of functions that is(are) able to read and iterpret the conditions part of the XML and turn it into a lambda expression on the fly.

I must mention that I have multiple XMLs and multiple CSVs.

Each of this CSVs must be checked agains a certain of the XMLs. 

The content of the conditions is (can be) different from one XML to another, but they all follow the same tags: and, or, eq, not-eq, field and literal. That is why I need a dynamic way of interpreting the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite an interesting problem. I have implemented eq and or as an example, you can implement neq and and.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from typing import List


class Evaluable:
    def eval(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ returns the outcome of the operation """
        raise NotImplemented


class OR(Evaluable):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.children: List[Evaluable] = [NODE.parse(child) for child in n]

    def eval(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ performs or operation for the children """
        return any([c.eval(*args, **kwargs) for c in self.children])


class EQ(Evaluable):
    def __init__(self, n):
        # parse field name
        self.field = n.find("field")
        if self.field is None:
            raise ValueError("field not found")
        self.field = self.field.text

        # parse literal value as str
        self.literal = n.find("literal")
        if self.literal is None:
            raise ValueError("literal not found")
        self.literal = self.literal.text

    def eval(self, *args, evaluation_params: dict = None, **kwargs):
        """ performs eq operation for the children """
        return evaluation_params[self.field] == self.literal


class NODE(Evaluable):
    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, n) -> Evaluable:
        if n.tag == "eq":
            return EQ(n)
        if n.tag == "or":
            return OR(n)


sample_xml = """<conditions>
    <or>
        <or>
              <eq>
                 <field>is_hazardous</field>
                 <literal>1</literal>
              </eq>
              <eq>
                 <field>is_refrigeration</field>
                 <literal>0</literal>
              </eq>
              <eq>
                 <field>year</field>
                 <literal>2005</literal>
              </eq>>
              <eq>
                 <field>material</field>
                 <literal>plastic</literal>
              </eq>>
        </or>
        <eq>
             <field>is_active</field>
             <literal>1</literal>
        </eq>>
    </or>
</conditions>"""

root = ET.fromstring(sample_xml)
node = NODE.parse(root[0])
parser = lambda x: node.eval(evaluation_params=x)
print(parser({"is_hazardous": "1",
              "is_refrigeration": "0",
              "year": "2006",
              "material": "metal",
              "is_active": "1"}))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! You're a life saver.